# Can [mustache] and [mustache.js] be merged?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Looking at [mustache](/questions/tagged/mustache) and [mustache.js](/questions/tagged/mustache.js) they have very similar tag descriptions and usage patterns and they talk about the same templating library.

I'd expect [mustache.js](/questions/tagged/mustache.js) questions to be Mustache+JavaScript specific but this is not the case. People can tell which port of mustache is being discussed using the language tag anyway.

I suggest merging [mustache](/questions/tagged/mustache) with [mustache.js](/questions/tagged/mustache.js).

Comment: Thanks for the quick resolution :)